# Partial View calling a method on the server every 5 second - No changes needed on the Page itself

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have a simple Partial View that I would like to automatically call a method on the server every 5 second.

Load the Partial View from the Master Layout:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("PingServer", "Account"); }
```

---

The Controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult PingServer()
{
     return PartialView("PingServer");
}
```

---

The actual "_PingServer" Partial View is:

```
@{
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
                 src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
    </script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            setInterval(Foo, 5000);
        });

        function Foo() {
            $.post("/Shared/ImHere.ashx", null, function () { });
        }    
    </script>
}
```

---

The Actual `"ImHere.ashx.cs"` looks like this:

```
public class ImHere : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
         SiteUser.ImHere();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

======================

> > THIS IS JUST NOT WORKING.

It actually used to work on MVC2 but NO MORE on MVC3. 
I understand the way Partial Views are handle in MVC3 is now a bit different with that concept of “_” (underscore) and not sure if that is the problem.
I tried renaming that partial view _PingServer …but still NO effect.

Maybe it’s that I load the Partial View as Html.RenderAction instead of Html.RenderPartial ?

The idea is that that call needs to run every 5 seconds and not change a single thing on the page.

Any thoughts??

Comment: Can I ask why do you need this every 5 seconds?

Comment: I'm guessing you've simplified a few things in your code before posting it. I think `RenderPartial`makes more sense. Also, how  about using a controller/action itself instead of an `ashx`. Lastly, you haven't mentioned what **is** wrong? Just nothing happens? Have you tried debugging in Chrome? Have you tried Fiddler or Firebug to see if the jquery is requesting the server?

Comment: This used to work on MVC2 ..
Shall I use anotehr control? Sure if it works ...but that was what i try to do when i was doing MVC2 and never worked. That's how i ended with the idea of using a "ashx" (because i could not make this work as a normal control).

How would you do a partial view control that calls the server every 5 seconds and that works on any page it's loaded?

Comment: @giddy: yes I simplified this page in order to focus on the problem.

@redsquare: my site has a concept (like skype) of "Online, Offline" status. when I'm "Online", people can see me. So I thought i needed a way for each person "Online" to ping the server in order to tell "I'm still Online". This will update the cached list of users "Online".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `RenderAction`, you can just use

```
@Html.Partial('partialName')
```

to render the partial view. Using this eliminates the need for the `PingServer()` action method.

Also your partial view shouldn't be within `@ { }` just

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
             src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        setInterval(Foo, 5000);
    });

    function Foo() {
        $.post("/Shared/ImHere.ashx", null, function () { });
    }    
</script>
```

as it is just HTML

Comment: Also can you confirm your ImHere handler works independently of this whole process such as by navigating to the URL directly?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Foo` javascript function you are calling the `/Shared/ImHere.ashx` handler so you shouldn't expect the `/Account/PingServer` action to ever be hit during the AJAX call. It will be hit only during the initial page load.

Master layout:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("PingServer", "Account"); }
```

Controller:

```
public class AccountController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult PingServer()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

Corresponding partial (`~/Views/Account/PingServer.cshtml`). Notice the removal of `@{}` blocks as they are not necessary as well as using an Url helper to build the url to the server script to avoid hardcoding it which might break if your application is hosted in a virtual directory inside IIS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        setInterval(Foo, 5000);
    });

    function Foo() {
        // here you are posting to an ASHX handler so don't expect
        // the controller action to ever be hit
        $.post('@Url.Content("~/Shared/ImHere.ashx")', null, function (result) { 
            // do something with the result of the AJAX call like update
            // some part of the DOM
        });
    }    
</script>
```

Comment: The following HTML is rendered BUT it NEVER HITS the server (BTW, I also added a page on Site/Shared/ImHere.ashx - and one under Views/Shared):

<body>
    <div id="online">
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                setInterval(Foo, 5000);
            });

            function Foo() {
                $.post("/Shared/ImHere.ashx", null, function () { });
            }    
        </script>
    </div>
</body>

Answer (score 0):

David, 
your last comment helped me finding the problem.

COMMENT: Also can you confirm your ImHere handler works independently of this whole process such as by navigating to the URL directly

> > PROBLEM: NAMESPACE MISMATCHING

When I added a NEW file to the project of type AHXS, Visual Studio by default gave it a namespace "ProjectName.DLLName.Folder" to both the HTML part and the CS.

I did rename the CS namespace to a different name (i.e ProjectName.Folder) but Visual Studio did not complained about it when i compiled.

Geeee ..such a novice mistake !!
Anyhow thanks all for helping out.